# How can i understand this inequality related to the ReLU activation function?

Tags: neural-networks

I am not sure why the following inequality is true:
$$
P\left(\text{ReLU} \circ f\right) \leq 2 \cdot P(f)
$$
Where $P(f)$ is the number of linear pieces in the function $f$. For example, if $f$ is a piecewise function with 2 pieces, then $P(f) = 2$. Also, how can I understand it for a neural network with 1 input and 1 output?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stats.stackexchange! To maximize the chance of someone answering your question, please consider using LaTeX to format your question. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial on how to do that. I have edited your question to give you a headstart.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r(x)$ denote RELU function. For $x\geq 0$, $r(x)=x$, so nothing changes on the RHS plane. The number of linear pieces stays the same on RHS. For $x<0$, $r(x)=0$, so the number of linear pieces is $1$. That means, while we'll have the same number of linear pieces for the RHS, we'll decrease the number of linear pieces to $1$ for the LHS. So, in general, it's a decrease in number of pieces.

But, we'll only increase it if a line segment crosses y-axis, because this line will be broken into two pieces, one staying as it is on the RHS plane, and one projected onto x-axis. Therefore, RELU will *double* the number of pieces for the line segment that crosses y-axis. In the utmost case, if there is only one line segment in $f$, e.g. $y=x$, RELU will double the number of pieces, but in all other cases, the resulting number of line segments be lower than $2P(f)$.